# First go program doesn't display index page

Tags: go

I followed creating a basic web app with go, I created the folder with name myApp. In myApp have main.go and public folder(in public have index.html), here is my content in main.go:

```
package main
import "net/http"
import "github.com/russross/blackfriday"

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/markdown",  GenerateMarkdown)
  http.Handle("/",  http.FileServer(http.Dir("public")))
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}  

func GenerateMarkdown(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  markdown := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(r.FormValue("body")))
  rw.Write(markdown)
}
```

I started server and go to http://localhost:8080/ but it doesn't link to index.html. Can anyone explain why it doesn't render index.html file. I'm a newbie in Golang.

Comment: How did you start the server?  Did you run the binary after a `go build`? Your code actually seems to work for me.

Comment: @oobivat I followed this command: go build and ./myApp

Comment: I'm sorry if this is really pedantic, but to clarify... While you were in the `myApp` folder you ran the command `go build`.  This command produces an executable binary (it isn't running yet).  Then you ran the binary (probably called `myApp`) by entering `./myApp` into the terminal.  I ask this only because your code works, unmodified, for me.

Comment: @oobivat first, thank you so much, after i ran these commands, it worked with this link : http://localhost:8080/public but i want it works with http://localhost:8080, please correct me if to have some thing went wrong.

Comment: Where's the `myApp` binary?  Is the `"public"` directory in the same place?

Comment: @oobivat Yes, `myApp`  binary the same place with `main.go` and `public` folder. In `public` folder i have `index.html, css folder & js folder`.

Comment: Then if `public/index.html` already exists and contains valid html, that is what you should see. Assuming your setup is as you say, that's all I can do because, as I said, this already works for me.

Comment: @oobivat Many thanks, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @oobivat You said, it work for you, here my picture ( http://postimg.org/image/s4wji2s9v/ ), is it the same structure with you?

Comment: What do you see when you go to `localhost:8080`?

Comment: I saw list of folders `public/`, `fileserver`, `main.go` , may be i have something went wrong with my config.

Comment: Then `http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))` isn't putting you in the right place for some reason. Try rebuilding the binary.  Keep playing and remember to alway recompile and execute the new binary after changes.  No offense, but I'm done replying here.

Comment: You're right @oobivat. I got it, i deleted my binary file and rebuild again, it worked. You saved my life :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in the comments, so here is a summary for completeness or something.

The code presented in the question produced the expected results after the actual build->run->test->repeat process was clarified for OP.  Points of clarification were as follows:

1. After using `go build` to compile the binary, the program isn't running yet.  Be sure to actually execute the binary before trying to connect to the server.
2. If it's necessary to make changes, stop the server, run `go build` again, then run the new binary.

As a side note, [gin](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) is a tool that tries to automate this process by rebuilding and launching your program each time you save the file.